# Multiple Threads Communication why output is not guaranteed though used wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading

### Am expecting output in a sequence of 7,100,1000 multipliers, sometimes it is showing but sometimes not. I didn't understand what went wrong with usage of wait and notify.

```
    package com.facebook.dao;

    public class ManyThreads {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            targets target = new targets();

            T1 x = new T1(target);
            T2 y = new T2(target);
            T3 z = new T3(target);

            Thread t1 = new Thread(x);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(y);
            Thread t3 = new Thread(z);

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t3.start();
        }

    }
```

> ```
>    class targets {
>         boolean twoFlag = false;
>         boolean threeFlag = true;
>         boolean fiveFlag = true;
>         int i = 7, j = 100, k = 1000;
>
>       public synchronized void twoMul() {
>             if (twoFlag) {
>                 try {
>                     wait();
>                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>                 }
>             }
>             System.out.println(i * 2);
>             threeFlag = false;
>             twoFlag = true;
>             notify();
> ```

```
        }

        public synchronized void threeMul() {

            if (threeFlag) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(j * 3);
            fiveFlag = false;
            threeFlag = true;
            notify();

        }

        public synchronized void fiveMul() {

            if (fiveFlag) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(k * 5);
            twoFlag = false;
            fiveFlag = true;
            notify();

        }

    }
```

> ```
>    class T1 implements Runnable {
>         targets t;
> ```

```
        T1(targets y) {
            this.t = y;
        }

    public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                t.twoMul();

            }
        }
    }

    class T2 implements Runnable {
        targets t;

        T2(targets y) {
            this.t = y;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                t.threeMul();

            }
        }
    }
```

> ```
>    class T3 implements Runnable {
>         targets t;
> ```

```
        T3(targets y) {
            this.t = y;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                t.fiveMul();

            }
        }
    }
```

I think am using flags properly but am wondering what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`notify()` notifies **one** of the waiting threads. So, after the T1 task has called `notify()`, either T2 or T3 will wake up, and proceed with its task.

Note that you're not looping to check the conditions. You're using `if`. So, as soon as the thread restarts, it goes out of the if block and continues.

BTW, even if that was the intention, it doesn't follow the rules described in the [documentation of `wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29): spurious wake-ups can happen, and wait should always be called inside a loop and check for the condition before going out of wait state.

So

1. use loops instead of `if`
2. Use `notifyAll()` instead of `notify()`

Comment: Thxs a lot.i agree with 2nd point.But loop i used in respective class it self.Is that doent work.

Comment: Wow!!!after using while loop instead If am always getting exact answer.Thxs JB Nizet..But i realy didnt understand why it is not working with If. can you expain in detail whats gng wrong with if

Comment: T1 starts, and isn't blocked because twoFlag is false. T2 and T3 are blocked. Then T1 sets threeFlag to true, and calls notify(). Then either T2 or T3 is woken up. You can't say. Whatever the thread, it goes out of the wait call, then goes out of the if, without checking the if condition again.